# Como fazer todas as combinações possíveis para chegar em um resultado proposto?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bom, vamos começar pelo começo, pela origem, o início do início.

Eu tenho esse programa:

```
from itertools import combinations
lis = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in (3, len(lis)):
    for comb in combinations(lis, i):
       if sum(comb) == 10:
           print (comb,'= 10')
```

A função dele, nada mais é que: Somar uma quantidade específica de números dentro de uma lista, de modo que obtenha o resultado estabelecido.

Suponhamos que a lista tenha 9 números, de 1 a 9. `lis = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
E eu queira que a quantidade de números somados entre si, seja 3. `for i in (3, len(lis)):`
E também determinei um resultado, nesse caso, o número 10. `if sum(comb) == 10:`

Obviamente a saída do programa será essa:

`(1, 2, 7) = 10`
`(1, 3, 6) = 10`
`(1, 4, 5) = 10`
`(2, 3, 5) = 10`

Rode o programa e veja com seus próprios olhos:

https://repl.it/@William33/RecentHeftyTern-10

Resumidamente, de forma sucinta e sintética, é a soma de todas combinações possíveis de uma determinada quantidade de números dentro da lista que darão o resultado proposto.

Agora, sabendo do que se trata, podemos prosseguir com a aplicação desse conhecimento.

Adivinha aonde ele será usado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso mesmo, em um quadrado mágico!

Pra quem ainda não sabe o que é um quadrado mágico, eis a explicação:

Quadrado Mágico é uma tabela quadrada igual a intersecção de números em que a soma de cada coluna, de cada linha e das duas diagonais são iguais.

Veja o exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Continuando:**

Olha só agora que interessante, para aplicar no programa eu "arranquei" as diagonais do quadrado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, está vendo "esses" resultados?`(107,113,119,150,131,137,143,149,141,133,150,117,109,101)`

Eu vou aplicar no programa com a quantidade `"5"` os números da matriz para somar todas as combinações possíveis que darão "esses" resultados, com exceção do 150 que será com a quantidade `"6"`.

Rode o programa e, não se preocupe, demorará menos de 30 segundos para encontrar todos os resultados:

https://repl.it/@William33/RecentHeftyTern-11

Agora finalmente, a questão magna!

Como fazer com que todas as combinações possíveis das somas de todos esses resultados obtidos nesse programa, se reagrupem de maneira que a matriz fique exatamente desta forma?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O programa imprimiria todas as possibilidades que chegarem a esses resultados com a matriz exatamente dessa forma, com os números dentro da matriz e seus resultados em volta.

## **Programa atualizado:**

https://repl.it/@William33/RecentHeftyTern-16

O que precisa ser feito nele é com que esses "resultados" repitam a mesma coisa que a função "combinations" fez para achar esses "resultados" mas dessa vez somando de 7 em 7 e o
if sum(comb) precisa ser igual ao resultado_final..

`for comb4 in combinations(lista, 7):`
`if sum(comb4) == resultado_final[1]:`

se for ele imprimira uma matriz assim:

MATRIZ

```
#....[47][16][41][10][35]....
#[05]....[48][17][42]....[29]
#[30][06]....[49]....[36][12]
#[13][31][07]....[43][19][37]
#[38][14]....[01]....[44][20]
#[21]....[08][33][02]....[45]
#....[15][40][09][34][03]....
```

e todas as possibilidades dessa matriz.. que derem os mesmos resultados...

RESULTADO FINAL

```
#[107][113][119][150][131][137][143]
#...................................[149]
#...................................[141]
#...................................[133]
#...................................[150]
#...................................[117]
#...................................[109]
#...................................[101]
```

Comment: Você irá entrar manualmente com os valores em vermelho e quer que o programa gere a matriz?

Comment: Sim tipo isso... eu entro com os valores em vermelho.. mas a matriz vai ter que ter um check pra ver se bateram todos os resultados vermelhos.. ai ela imprimi todas as matrizes que baterem esses resultados...

Comment: Sempre deixando as diagonais em branco?

Comment: Sim.. sempre em branco..

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ?

Comment: Curiosidade: qual seria o objetivo disso?

Comment: Você quer checar todos os resultados possíveis, ou ter um resultado que satisfaça o problema proposto?

Comment: Qual o proposito? Qual a tua dúvida?