# Combinação de valores pra seleção de amostras

Tags: python

Moçada, estou tendo dificuldades pra finalizar um trabalho e gostaria de ajuda. Enfim, abaixo está o trecho da minha lista.csv:

```
n,NOME,COR,VALOR
1,Lapis ,Verde,"11,1"
2,Caneta ,Vermelho,"12,25"
3,Lapiseira ,Azul,"15,45"
...
```

e o código que escrevi em Python:

```
from itertools import combinations
import csv

def get_column_of_csv(filename, column):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        catalogo = csv.DictReader(stream)
        for row in catalogo:
            yield row[column]

for name in get_column_of_csv('lista.csv', 'VALOR'):
    for i in (2, len(name)):
            for comb in combinations(name, i):
                if sum(int(comb)) <= 25:
                    print (comb,'<= 25,00')

    print(name)
```

Minha intenção é fazer com que o código combine valores de forma que a soma deles não ultrapasse determinados valor estabelecido e ao final me mostre os nomes dos itens cujo os pares não ultrapassaram esse valor. 
Um exemplo de saída seria: 
"Lápis + Lapiseira" (Já que a soma destes não ultrapassa o valor de 25,00 pré estabelecido).

Eu vi esse post: [LINK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266507/como-fazer-todas-as-combina%C3%A7%C3%B5es-poss%C3%ADveis-para-chegar-em-um-resultado-proposto) pra me basear no meu código, porém, não obtive sucesso.

ERRO:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kits.py", line 13, in <module>
    if sum(int(comb)) <= 25:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar... ficaria grato.

EXTRA: Se na lista de itens eu tivesse o nome do item junto com a fabricante (ex: Caneta BIC, Caneta Faber-Castell,...) e eu quisesse montar combinação só de itens de determinada marca, ou excluir uma determinada marca do filtro, como poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-combinations-filter1)

Uma solução com o pandas, utilizei os dados do seu exemplo mas adicionei as marcas para poder demonstrar a filtragem, eliminando as linhas com a marca "bar":

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

# Simulando o csv
csv = '''
nome,cor,marca,valor
Lapis, Verde, bic,"11,1"
Caneta, Vermelho, cristal,"12,25"
Lapiseira, Azul, foo,"15,45"
Lapis, Verde, foo,"12,00"
borracha, Branca, bar,"10,00"
borracha, Verde, bar,"11,00"
'''

# Lendo o csv 
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))

# Filtrando o df para que nao contenha a marca 'bar'
df = df[~df.marca.str.contains('bar')]

# Criando coluna para uma tupla de descricao e valor (adapte ao seu contexto)
df['descricao'] = df.nome + df.cor + df.marca
df['item'] = list(zip(df.descricao, df.valor))

# Apresentando o dataframe resultante
print(df)
```

Saída:

```
        nome        cor     marca  valor                descricao  \
0      Lapis      Verde       bic   11.1          Lapis Verde bic   
1     Caneta   Vermelho   cristal  12.25  Caneta Vermelho cristal   
2  Lapiseira       Azul       foo  15.45       Lapiseira Azul foo   
3      Lapis      Verde       foo  12.00          Lapis Verde foo   

                               item  
0           (Lapis Verde bic, 11.1)  
1  (Caneta Vermelho cristal, 12.25)  
2       (Lapiseira Azul foo, 15.45)  
3          (Lapis Verde foo, 12.00)
```

O próximo passo é combinar os itens em uma lista:

```
# Fazendo as combinacoes
combs = list(combinations(df.item, 2))

# Apresentando as combinacoes
print(combs)
```

Saída:

```
[(('Lapis Verde bic', '11.1'), ('Caneta Vermelho cristal', '12.25')),
 (('Lapis Verde bic', '11.1'), ('Lapiseira Azul foo', '15.45')),
 (('Lapis Verde bic', '11.1'), ('Lapis Verde foo', '12.00')),
 (('Caneta Vermelho cristal', '12.25'), ('Lapiseira Azul foo', '15.45')),
 (('Caneta Vermelho cristal', '12.25'), ('Lapis Verde foo', '12.00')),
 (('Lapiseira Azul foo', '15.45'), ('Lapis Verde foo', '12.00'))]
```

Finalmente percorremos a lista das combinacoes, selecionando as que atendem à condição, no caso soma dos valores <= 25

```
# Selecionando as combinacoes validas
valid_combs = []
max_value = 25
for comb in combs:
    if float(comb[0][1]) + float(comb[1][1]) <= max_value:
        valid_combs.append(comb)

# Apresentando o resultado
print(valid_combs)
```

Saída (Tuplas com as combinacoes <= 25):

```
[(('Lapis Verde bic', '11.1'), ('Caneta Vermelho cristal', '12.25')),
 (('Lapis Verde bic', '11.1'), ('Lapis Verde foo', '12.00')),
 (('Caneta Vermelho cristal', '12.25'), ('Lapis Verde foo', '12.00'))]
```

**Colocando o resultado final em um `pandas.DataFrame`:**

```
final_list = []
for valid in valid_combs:
    final_list.append((valid[0][0],valid[0][1], valid[1][0],valid[1][1], 
                       float(valid[0][1])+float(valid[1][1])))

df_final = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns=['Item 1', 'Valor', 
                                              'Item 2', 'Valor', 'Total'])

# Apresentando o resultado final
print(df_final)
```

Saída:

```
                    Item 1  Valor                   Item 2  Valor  Total
0          Lapis Verde bic   11.1  Caneta Vermelho cristal  12.25  23.35
1          Lapis Verde bic   11.1          Lapis Verde foo  12.00  23.10
2  Caneta Vermelho cristal  12.25          Lapis Verde foo  12.00  24.25
```

**Filtrando o `DataFrame` final:**

Vamos filtrar o resultado final removendo as linhas em que apareça a palavra "Caneta"

```
# Filtrando o df, removendo as combinacoes q tenham "Caneta"
df_filtered = df_final[~df_final['Item 1'].str.contains('Caneta') & 
                       ~df_final['Item 2'].str.contains('Caneta')]

# Apresentando o dataframe filtrado
print('','DataFrame filtrado: ', df_filtered,sep='\n')
```

Saída

```
DataFrame filtrado: 
            Item 1 Valor           Item 2  Valor  Total
1  Lapis Verde bic  11.1  Lapis Verde foo  12.00   23.1
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-combinations-filter1)

Comment: Olá Sidon, muito obrigado pela resposta. Pandas é muito legal, mas infelizmente está em um nível muito além do meu conhecimento... rs. Porém, eu coloquei o código e funcionou bem. Eu só não gostei muito da saída, porque a lista é muuuito grande, então acaba ficando muito embolado e cheio de caracteres especiais. Isso é possível de ser melhorado? Semelhante ao que foi feito no Dataframe...

Comment: É só colocar as combinacoes validas em um dataframe, estou editando a resposta para colocar o resultado final em um `df`,

Comment: Atualizado tb no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-combinations-filter1)

Comment: Detalhe: O pandas só parece complexo, mas depois q vc acostuma verá que é uma "mão na roda" para finanças, data-sciencie, tabulação, etc. Um canivete suiço na big data. :-)

Comment: Obrigado Sidon.

Comment: Sidon, surgiu uma dúvida... Meu aquivo .csv é externo, então pra eu abrir ele acredito que o comando seja:  `df = pd.read_csv('LISTA.csv')` certo?! Se, nesse arquivo o cabeçalho tenha um título de duas palavras (ex.: MENOR VALOR), como eu teria de definir a linha 29 do seu código?
E mais uma pergunta, vamos supor que eu queira excluir da combinação alguns itens do cabeçalho NOME (ex.: Lápis), como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: A abertura do arquivo esta correta, as outras perguntas eu nao entendi, vc gostaria de descartar a primeira linha do arquivo, é isso? Linha 29? o que tem nela. Excluir da combinação ou do df final?  O "papo" esta ficando específico. :-)

Comment: Na verdade minha intenção é aprender com funciona a entrada de dados. Na linha 29 você definiu `df['descricao'] = df.nome + df.cor + df.marca` já que os itens do cabeçalho são: `nome,cor,marca,valor`. Se  no lugar de 'valor' eu tivesse duas strings, como por exemplo 'menor valor', como eu definiria ela? `df.menor valor` (...só um exemplo). 
E a outra pergunta, eu acredito que seja mais complexa, mas é de saber como excluir valores da combinação... por exemplo, eu quero uma combinação somente de itens LAPIS, assim ignorando os demais (LAPISEIRA e CANETA)... isso é simples de ser feito?

Comment: Ok, Editei a resposta e acrescentei o tópico **Filtrando o dataframe final:** Tentei responder tudo nesse topico, veja que agora estou referenciando as colunas de outra forma, pq o nome delas são compostas ao invés de `df.label` estou fazendo `df["label"]` como em `df_final['Item 1']`. Também faço um filtro removendo as linhas que tenha a plavra "Caneta", O filtro poderia ser invertido tb, ou seja, só considerar as linhas que tivesse a palavra `Caneta`, para isto bastaria remover o sinal de negação `~` e substituir `&` por `|`

Comment: Entendi, obrigado. Aliás, a linha 22 ficaria `df["MENOR VALOR"] = df["MENOR VALOR"].str.replace(',','.')` assim?!

Comment: Isso, isso, isso! :-)

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.

Comment: Sidon, prometo que é a ultima dúvida. Pra eu filtrar mais de uma palavra eu tenho que fazer assim (linha 55): `df_filtered = df_final[~df_final['Item 1'].str.contains('CANETA', 'LAPIS')`? Eu tentei, mas não deu certo. E eu também aproveitei e fiz um teste pra uma lista bem grande e notei que o resultado tem apresentado valores: ''...'', porque? Tentei exportar pra .csv o resultado, mas não deu certo, continua aparecento o termo de continuação. Isso é possível de ser corrigido? Como?!

Comment: `df_caneta_lapis = df_final[df_final['Item 1'].str.contains('Caneta') | df_final['Item 2'].str.contains('Lapis')]` Para evitar os pontinhos no `print()`:  `pd.options.display.max_rows = 999` e `pd.options.display.max_columns = 999`. Da uma olhada no repl.it, atualizei lá.

Comment: Altere os valores de `pd.options.display` para a sua necessidade.

Comment: Deu certinho. Muitíssimo obrigado, de verdade. Aliás, só um detalhe que percebi depois da modificação, imagina que eu fosse fazer a impressão do resultado... a 'Lista 1' com os valores ficou numa folha e a 'Lista 2' está em outra. Dificultando um pouco a visualização... você sabe oque pode ter acarretado isso?

Comment: Sem ver fica dificil imaginar o que seja, mas geralmente o pandas tenta ajustar a visualizacao quando o numero de colunas não cabe na area de impressao, ai nao tem jeito vai ficar dificil a visualizacao mesmo, mas vc pode tenar o pacote [tabulate](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate). Lembra q vc reclamou da visualização das combinacoes (tuplas) com o `print()` puro? Agora fiz uma apresentação com o tabulate no repl.it, Dá uma olhada lá.

Comment: Ficou assim: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Zt4hD2zXY7/

Comment: Então... isso indica que espaço de visualização que vc esta tentando fazer a apresentação não comporta todas as colunas, então, inteligentemente, o pandas quebra em 2. Faça um teste, tente assim `print('','DataFrame filtrado: ', df_filtered.to_string(), sep='\n')` e vc verá q a impressao agora será truncada, pq eu converti para string antes. Vc pode fazer testes no replit. Deixe a janela onde apresenta os resultados bem estreita e vjea a diferenca do `print(df.to_string())`, para somente `print(df)`, na verdade o pandas está te ajudando, sem isso fica tudo bagunçado.

Comment: Se o espaço para a apresentacao não é suficiente vc vai ter que reduzir as informacoes nas colunas, tipo apresentar somente o codigo do item ao inves da descricao ou ainda somente uma parte da descricao, truncando em um posicao determinada, por ex.

Comment: Sidon, usando o `df_filtered.to_string()` deu certinho. Muitíssimo obrigado. Vou começar a estudar Pandas, me motivou.

Answer (score 2):

O erro é basicamente porque você está tentando converter uma tupla em um inteiro. Basicamente fazendo algo como:

```
int((2, 5, 7))
```

E a classe `int` não sabe o que fazer com uma tupla.

Achei alguns pontos do código um pouco confuso, principalmente a linha `for i in (2, len(name))`; não entendi porque você irá gerar as combinações com 2 itens e com `len(name)` itens. Como você está acessando a coluna `'VALOR'`, o valor de `name` será, por exemplo, `"11,1"`, e assim `len(name)` seria 4. Depois disso você gera as combinações em `name` com `i` itens, mas isso geraria combinações entre os caracteres de `"11,1"` que não é o que você pretende fazer.

Seu código vai ficar bem mais simples se você separar as responsabilidades por funções. O primeiro passo é obter os dados do arquivo, então fazemos a função que lê o arquivo retornando um gerador para as linhas já convertendo o valor de `VALOR` para `float`:

```
def read_csv(path):
    with open(path) as stream:
        reader = csv.DictReader(stream)
        for row in reader:
            row['VALOR'] = float(row['VALOR'].replace(',', '.'))
            yield row
```

A partir do resultado desejamos criar as combinações 2 a 2, então utilizamos a função `itertools.combinations`:

```
data = read_csv('data.csv')
combinations = itertools.combinations(data, 2)
```

De todas as combinações só nos interessa aquelas que possuem a soma da coluna `VALOR` menor ou igual a 25. Para isso criamos uma função que receberá a sequência de combinações, o nome da coluna que desejamos somar e o limite desejado:

```
def sum_of_column_le(combinations, column, limit):
    for combination in combinations:
        sum_of_column = sum(product.get(column, 0) for product in combination)
        if sum_of_column <= limit:
            yield combination
```

Assim, para obtermos as combinações que possuem a soma de `VALOR` menor ou igual a 25 fazemos:

```
result = sum_of_column_le(combinations, 'VALOR', 25.00)
```

E, assim, podemos iterar sobre `result` para exibir as combinações que nos interessa:

```
for combination in result:
    print([product['NOME'] for product in combination])
```

Para os dados da pergunta:

```
n,NOME,COR,VALOR
1,Lapis ,Verde,"11,1"
2,Caneta ,Vermelho,"12,25"
3,Lapiseira ,Azul,"15,45"
```

A saída seria:

```
['Lapis ', 'Caneta ']
```

Pois é a última combinação de produtos que possui a soma de valores menor ou igual a 25.

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-373762) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/f85603de368e6f65aa4c03f80984f8cb)</sup>

Comment: Aderson, obrigado pela sua resposta. Ele funcionou legal. Eu só fiquei com uma dúvida, é possível melhorar a mensagem de saída? E sobre o 'EXTRA' que havia comentado... caso eu quisesse que ele iterasse somente os itens que tivesse cor vermelha (por exemplo), você poderia me orientar em como fazer?

Comment: @MarceloJoão Sim, tendo as informações você pode gerar a saída que desejar. Sobre o EXTRA, é possível filtrar assim que você lê o arquivo em `read_csv`; ali basta você fazer a validação que deseja e só efetuar o `yield` dos itens que passarem na validação.

Comment: Entendi. Só pra esclarecer... a saída no caso, ela sai desse formato: ['Lapis ', 'Caneta ']; 
É possível de fazer sair: Lapis + Caneta ?

Comment: Sim, pode fazer o que desejar. Quem define a saída é o `print` em `for combination in result`; basta alterá-lo conforme suas necessidades;

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.

Comment: Anderson, me surgiu só mais uma dúvida... a saída está com repetição, por exemplo: Lápis + Caneta e Caneta + Lápis. Isso é fácil de filtrar? Pra não acontecer repetições...

Comment: @MarceloJoão Você deve ter feito algo diferente. Da forma da resposta ele não gera essa combinação duplicada; as combinações que ele gera é (Lápis, Caneta), (Lápis, Lapiseira) e (Lapiseira, Caneta).

Comment: Verdade, eu me confundi. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Alterei um pouco seu código e funcionou direitinho aqui.

O que fiz:

- Peguei a coluna **NOME** e joguei todos os itens em uma lista;
- Peguei a coluna **VALOR** e joguei todos os itens em uma lista;
- Fiz um replace na colunar **VALOR** e alterei todas as **','** por **'.'** para poder converter em float.
- Descobri os index em que a soma dos produtos fica abaixo de 25.

Com isso, o código ficou assim:

```
from itertools import combinations
import csv

lista_valor = []
lista_produto = []
combinacoes_possiveis = []
resultado = []

def get_column_of_csv(filename, column):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        catalogo = csv.DictReader(stream)
        for row in catalogo:
            yield row[column]

for produto in get_column_of_csv('lista.csv', 'NOME'):

    lista_produto.append(produto)


for name in get_column_of_csv('lista.csv', 'VALOR'):
    name = str(name)                # TRANSFORMA EM STRING PARA PODER USAR REPLACE
    name = name.replace(',', '.')   # TROCA , POR . PARA PODER CONVERTER EM FLOAT
    name = float(name)              # CONVERTE EM FLOAT

    lista_valor.append(name)        # ADICIONA O VALOR A UMA LISTA


# --------BUSCA COMBINAÇÃO DE 2 VALORES DA LISTA-----------------
# --------------QUE NÃO ULTRAPASSAM 25---------------------------

for t in combinations(lista_valor,2):
    if sum(t) <= 25:
        idx = [lista_valor.index(a) for a in t]    # PEGA O INDEX NO QUAL A COMBINAÇÃO
                                                   # NÃO ULTRAPASSA 25

        combinacoes_possiveis.append(idx)



print(combinacoes_possiveis)     # PARES DE ÍNDICES POSSÍVEIS

for i in range(len(combinacoes_possiveis)):  ### PREVINE RESULTADOS REPETIDOS

  if str(lista_produto[combinacoes_possiveis[i][0]]) + 'e ' + 
  str(lista_produto[combinacoes_possiveis[i][1]]) in resultado:
    print('Elemento repetido')

  else:

    resultado.append(str(lista_produto[combinacoes_possiveis[i][0]]) + 'e ' +
    str(lista_produto[combinacoes_possiveis[i][1]]))


print(resultado)     # ['Lapis e Caneta ', 'Lapis e Lapiseira ', 'Lapis e Boracha ', 'Lapis e Caneta Colorida ', 'Lapis e Corretivo ', 'Caneta e Lapiseira ', 'Caneta e Boracha ', 'Caneta e Caneta Colorida ', 'Caneta e Corretivo ', 'Lapiseira e Boracha ', 'Lapiseira e Lapiseira ', 'Lapiseira e Caneta Colorida ', 'Lapiseira e Corretivo ', 'Boracha e Lapiseira ', 'Boracha e Caneta Colorida ', 'Boracha e Corretivo ', 'Caneta Colorida e Corretivo ']
```

Boa sorte com os estudos!

**EDIT:**

Alterei todos os valores do CSV para que houvessem 21 combinações possíveis.

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado pela resposta... ótimo ideia você teve. Porém, ele fez oque eu quero, mas não necessariamente oque eu preciso. Ele só me mostrou uma combinação e não todas as possíveis (sem repetição, claro). Por que?

Comment: Então, Marcelo, se você printar o idx dentro do **for** vai ver que ele retorna todas as combinações possíveis de pares (que foi o definido duas linhas acima) pelo index da combinação. No exemplo que eu fiz, ele retorna [0, 1] pois são os elementos da lista que a combinação é possível. Se você alterar os valores e todas as combinações forem possíveis, o idx retornará: `[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 2]` que são as combinações possíveis. Espero que tenha conseguido compreender!

Comment: Olá Guilherme, obrigado pela atenção. Eu, infelizmente, estou iniciando meus estudos então... eu não entendi muito bem oque eu deveria editar pra que ele criasse combinações com todos os elementos da lista. Se você puder me mostrar eu ficaria muito grato.

Comment: Marcelo, editei o código e tentei deixar um pouco mais fácil de entender.
Primeiro, eu alterei os valores dos produtos para 5,00 para ser possíveis todas as combinações. Depois, criei uma nova lista (combinacoes_possiveis) para adicionar os index dos elementos nela.

Na linha 41 eu adicionei os index das combinações que são possíveis de serem feitas à nova lista criada. Assim, eu possuo todas as posições do CSV em que a condição é verdadeira.

Nos prints no final do código, dá pra ter uma noção melhor agora de como usar esses indexs. Espero que tenha facilitado seu entendimento dessa vez!

Comment: Acredito que entendi sim. O detalhe é que a lista tem cerca de 350 itens, então são muitas combinações, se eu tiver que adicionar uma pra cada... acho que não ia resolver meu problema (...se eu entendi bem o código).

Comment: Marcelo, eu editei novamente o código para ficar global. Fiz o teste com 21 combinações possíveis e deu certo. Criei uma nova lista para armazenar os resultados finais, e adicionei a ela os nomes dos produtos onde é possível a combinação. Você pode encontrar a alteração no fim do código (linha 50).

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme.